# Pug error with hyphen

Tags: pug

```
nav(class='nav')
    a(href='./')
        img(src='https://0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661.000webhostapp.com/home.png')
    ul
        strong
            each cate in allCategory
                li(class='inline-block' style={line-height:10+'px'})
                    a(class='block' href='./'+cate.slug style={padding:10+'px'}) #{cate.name}
```

hyphen (-) error at line-height

Answer (score 0):

You may use the right syntax as below

```
li(class='inline-block' style="{line-height:10+'px'}")
```

Else, a much meaningful way as,

```
li.inline-block(style='line-height:10px')
```